# Material UI (Scrollspy) - React - use tabs to move through list and auto scroll to index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tabs, material-ui

If I had a large list of items that each had a category,

```
const categories: string[] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const items: {name: string, category: number}[] = [{name: "foo", category: 1}, {name: "bar", category: 1}, {name: "foobar", category: 2}, {name: "barfoo", category: 3}, ... etc.];
```

..and in material-ui they were used as a tab header for the categories:

```
  <AppBar>
    <Tabs
      value={tabIndex}
      onChange={handleChange}
      indicatorColor="secondary"
      variant="scrollable"
      scrollButtons="auto"
    >
      {categories.map((i) => (
        <Tab
          key={i}
          label={i}
        />
      ))}
    </Tabs>
  </AppBar>
```

I then had a long list of the items underneath the tabs header that are sorted together by their category.

How could I use the tabs to move through sequentially through the list by autoscrolling to the first category in the position based on the tab selected as well as auto updating the tab position when scrolling past the specific first index in the list.

For a visual example:

[Example image to use tabs to move through sequential content that needs to be read in a particular order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0fvd.png)

How could I achieve something like this in material ui & react? In summary,

1. Scroll through a large list of items that have and are sorted by categories
2. **Auto scroll** to first list position category from tab select
3. **Auto select** a tab based on the list scroll position

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer is above but there is also [this CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-xu80m?file=/index.js) that will also work.

Answer (score 4):

The component you are looking for is [**Scrollspy**](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16359) and it is [**future component**](https://material-ui.com/discover-more/roadmap/#main-content) of material ui.

Currently they have component implemented in material ui doc with name [AppTableOfContents](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/9bf9e82bfaef83857e74eca877b33c4e503626a9/docs/src/modules/components/AppTableOfContents.js). If you see in doc at right-hand-side there is **Contents** section.

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16359
here I found two solution

1. Use [**react-scrollspy**](https://github.com/makotot/react-scrollspy)
2. Use [**useScrollspy Hook**](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16359#issuecomment-617365879) (try this)

Comment: Thank you so much. I was losing my mind trying to find the name for this. Awesome answer, thank you!